# Creating file using PHP imagepng function in Openshift

Tags: php, openshift, redhat

I use imagepng() to save an image using PHP.
It work fine in another hosting, but I can't make it work in Openshift Redhat.

> imagepng($rImg, 'myImg.png');

I tried to save it to directory and give permissions (`chmod 777`) to this directory but it didn't help.
I also tried to add a prefix of 
`dirname(__FILE__)`
to the path but it didn't work and I can't create the image file. I know that the file has not been created because I searched for it in the server and didn't find anything.
Is there a way to create an image file using imagepng() in Openshift?

Comment: I have tried in my free openshift account and all works fine **without any customization** or permission change. Are you sure that problem don't is precedent (image creation)? Try to isolate bug: output png in browser instead to save-it, check the error log in openshift console or echo result of functions in critical points.